# facebook application invite incentive

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, points

I'm trying to make a facebook game that allows users to invite friends. I'd like to provide an incentive that people who invite others get 1 bonus point for every 10 points that their invitee gets.
I'm developing the facebook app on Google App Engine using the Python runtime.

What is the best way to implement this kind of feature? I know that I can find out who invited a given app user. I want to account for a lot of users and want to conserve as many server resources as possible.

I was thinking to create a 'User' entity, where there is a 'id' value, a 'points' value and a 'referred from' value. When points are added to for a user, the server looks up the 'referred from' entity and awards points accordingly. But since I am only awarding 1 point for every 10, it might be a waste for the server to check every time whether points mod 10 is 0. Also, if invitation points are carried through, it seems like the entire User datastore namespace would constantly be propagating points, which is also wasteful.

Any good way to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, as you observe, is to update the parent entity every time the user earns a total of 10 points. If they only earn one point at a time, the maximum overhead for this is 10%.

A more efficient option might be to set a flag whenever a user earns points, and once a day, run a mapreduce or other similar job that sums up all the points for a user's referrals who have that flag set and adds it to their total.

Comment: so the flags would be like 'user1flag', 'user2flag', etc. and these would be appended as properties of the users that the original user referred right?

Comment: @ejang No, just a single flag that indicates if the score's been updated. Then for each user who's had referrals, you can query for users they referred who have the flag set. Or, using mapreduce, do the equivalent without needing separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is against faecbooks [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/policy_checklist/english/)

> App does not directly reward or require users to use Facebook Social
>   channels, such as Feed stories and Requests.

Comment: He's not talking about rewarding for using social channels, he's talking about giving existing users a share of the "points" that new users earn. "Points" appears to be an in-app concept and as long as its not tied to creating stories etc its fine.

Comment: yep, points are an in-app concept that are earned playing the game. I was wondering how bonus points could be awarded based on invitee's earning points in-game.

Comment: what you are saying is - if you invite more friends you will get more points - that is incentive.

Comment: just checked with facebook developers: "Should be ok so long as they don't get points for inviting friends, but only for actions after the friends have accepted the invite". so i think my proposal is valid, but if someone could tell me how to design the datastore writes that would be great.